# Node.js return html as a variable

Tags: html, node.js, request

I'm setting up a web scraper using Node.js and want to grab some html from a url and save it as a variable.  A stripped down version follows.

```
var request = require('request');
var get_html = function(){
    var url = "http://www.google.com";
    var html = '';
    request.get(url,function(error, response, body){
        html += body;
    });
    return html;
};
console.log(get_html());
```

It seems that the function returns before request can concatenate the html to the variable `html`.  As far as I can see, request only allows me to manipulate the html within the callback function or pipe it to a file.  Is there anyway to just return it as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.get is asynchronous and it will return result in the callback function.

You need to adapt your code a little bit like this

```
var request = require('request');

// get_html receive callback to process result
var get_html = function(callback) {
    var url = "http://www.google.com";
    var html = '';
    request.get(url,function(error, response, body){
        return callback(body); // call callback and parse result to it
    });
};

// call get_html function
// and log html result here
get_html(function (body) { console.log(body); });
```

Code with a lot of function callbacks looks not beautiful.
I prefer promise than callback.
If you wish to use promise, try 'request-promise' lib.

Comment: So it looks like there's no way to actually return the html as a string, only to pass the rest of the code into request as a callback?  I mean to use this small function as a utility that can be called by different modules.  It sounds like this will get unwieldy quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `request.get` is async, so you have to put `return html;` in the callback. Otherwise it's returning instantly, before request.get can finish running.